# How can I set the fan on my laptop to a constant level

Tags: laptop, fan

The fan on my laptop turns on very loud after the laptop has been on for a few minutes. Then it oscillates between loud and soft every few minutes. I already dusted the inside, and it happens regardless of what programs are running. The laptop does not feel hot. I messed around with speedfan but couldn't make it work.

Samsung 700z3a is what I have.

Comment: Please include the manufacturer and model number.

Comment: Most of the time you can't. I went 6 rounds with HP trying to get them to give me a bios with fan controls, or at least get it to work with speedfan to set them, but they wouldn't or couldn't.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Speedfan (available at [almico.com](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php)) is one of the best. Since you already tried it, but could not get it to work on your system, try sending in the details report from within the program to the author. That way, he will have some data to add support for your system to his application. If it is mechanically possible to control your fan through software, he may then decide to add this support.

Comment: You can't. The fan has to change speeds to keep the CPU at a safe temperature. There's simply no other way to avoid overheating or overcooling. You're going to have to find and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fan speed is controlled by the BIOS, and if the BIOS does not cooperate with Speedfan then there's not much you can do from the software side.

Physically, you can open up the laptop and disconnect the fan sensor wire. This would make the fan run at 100% all the time. If this is undesirable, you could further modify the fan with a resistor on the power supply to get the desired constant speed.

The fan should look like this. You would cut the white wire. It might cause the BIOS to freak out and give you warnings about a fan failure.

[image: KSB0705HA Fan]

Note: I don't actually recommend doing this. Do so at your own risk.